# How to zoom overview diagram in gojs?

Tags: gojs

Im trying to zoom overview diagram but its not working:

```
    let myOverview = $(go.Overview, myOverviewDiv, {
        observed: diagram,
        contentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
        scale: 10.0
    });
```

Any suggestion how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The **Overview** constructor does this:
   this.autoScale = go.Diagram.Uniform;

You will need to set your overview's autoScale property back to the default value, `go.Diagram.None`.

You will find that setting **Diagram.scale** won't work then either. That is what the **Diagram.initialScale** property is for. But even that might not work on Overviews, since the scale is probably reset when setting the observed diagram.